# Zend\Crypt, generating salt

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, md5, salt

When i generating salt with Zend\Crypt, line has a size of 60 characters, like this "string(60) "$2a$14$bG9vbG9sb2xvaXA5aXBpOOzbeNtKouOS22IEgWwwFrHv08Do5yuSS""

```
 $bcrypt = new Bcrypt();
 $pswd = 'some_pswd';
 $securePass = $bcrypt->create($pswd);
```

How i can change string length to 30?

Answer (score 1):

Your code generates a BCrypt hash, including an automatically generated salt (the part after the third `$ bG9vbG9sb2xvaXA5aXBpOO`). A BCrypt hash always results in a 60 character string.

Why do you expect/need a 30 character string? You would have to use another hash algorithm, but for passwords BCrypt is a good choice, with only 30 characters the hash would be unsafe.